# Deleting data linked to another database table in SQL Server database using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm trying to delete one of the following rows from my database:

[image]

with this code:

```
public ActionResult DeleteRowUsers(int id)
{
        var status = false;
        var message = "";

        using (ConcurrentDBEntities2 db = new ConcurrentDBEntities2())
        {
            var data = db.Companies.Find(id);

            if (data != null)
            {
                db.Companies.Remove(data);
                db.SaveChanges();
                status = true;
            }
            else
            {
                message = "Error!";
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Users");
        }
}
```

However the `CompanyID` is linked to another table:

[image]

When I try to delete this I'm getting the following error:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint \"FK_ApiRedirect_CompanyID\". The conflict occurred in database \"ConcurrentDB\", table \"dbo.ApiRedirects\", column 'CompanyID'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated.

What I would like to achieve is that both getting deleted, the entire row in the first table and all the linked items in other table.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: either change FK to cascade delete or delete child rows before deleting parent

Comment: Where can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the class where you are extending the `DbContext` (it should look something like this):

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
  ...
}
```

you need to override the `OnModelCreating()` method like so:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
    modelBuilder.Entity<Companies>()
            .HasOne(c => c.CompanyId)
            .WithMany(a => a.ApiRedirects)
            .HasForeignKey(a => a.CompanyId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
  }
}
```

But probably this will require to recreate your database in order to apply this change. However this is the way you can manipulate the `DeleteBehavior` in EF.